# How widely is “catch-22” used?

Tags: nouns, word-usage

I have known for a long time that there is noun called “catch-22” in English. In some cases, I really would like to use it but I'm not sure if it is a well known term.

AFAIK, it is used when you are stuck between two things. For instance:

> You can't get a job without any
>   experience and you can't get any
>   experience without a job. It is
>   catch-22.

How widely is “catch-22” used?

Comment: I think it's one of the classic terms in the language. I'd wager that it's recognized by >50% of English speakers.

Comment: here's [some mentions of Catch-22 in the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/keyword/catch-22)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the title of a classic [Joseph Heller novel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0684833395) about World War II, published in 1961 and adapted for film in 1970.  Heller invented the term to describe absurd, impossible-to-escape situations; he actually uses it rather loosely, so that it can cover almost anything.
The main statement of the concept:

> There was only one catch and that was
>   Catch-22, which specified that a
>   concern for one's own safety in the
>   face of dangers that were real and
>   immediate was the process of a
>   rational mind. Orr was crazy and could
>   be grounded. All he had to do was ask;
>   and as soon as he did, he would no
>   longer be crazy and would have to fly
>   more missions. Orr would be crazy to
>   fly more missions and sane if he
>   didn't, but if he was sane, he had to
>   fly them. If he flew them, he was
>   crazy and didn't have to; but if he
>   didn't want to, he was sane and had
>   to. Yossarian was moved very deeply by
>   the absolute simplicity of this clause
>   of Catch-22 and let out a respectful
>   whistle.
>
> "That's some catch, that Catch-22," he
>   observed.
>
> "It's the best there is," Doc Daneeka
>   agreed.

Some other examples:

> Catch-22 states that agents enforcing
>   Catch-22 need not prove that Catch-22
>   actually contains whatever provision
>   the accused violator is accused of
>   violating.

and

> Catch-22 says they have a right to do
>   anything we can’t stop them from
>   doing.

Catch-22 is an enhanced version of the classic ["Damned if you do, and damned if you don't."](http://books.google.com/books?id=R5IPAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=%22damned%20if%20you%20do%22&source=bl&ots=6XjHOBJsgY&sig=Ka8isVbIZ2M832ZcM2Ly99dsorY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oAMgUN-tPKaZiQLGqYCQBw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22damned%20if%20you%20do%22&f=false)

Now, how widely known is the phrase?  In the United States, very nearly universal - even among people who've never read or heard of the book and movie.  In the rest of the English-speaking world?  I have no idea...

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(disambiguation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_%28disambiguation%29)

---

Even if people don't fully understand "catch-22" they probably get that it means basically "to be stuck between a rock and a hard place".

Comment: +1 for explanation and the last paragraph. We know the book and have read it in the rest of the world, even the non-English speaking ;)

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, I wonder how many people use this term without knowing the book by Joseph Heller? A great example is also seen in the M*A*S*H character Klinger, whose attempts to act infirm merely underscore his rationality and are insufficient to warrant his discharge.

Comment: @TheRaven, I suspect quite a lot.

Comment: I'd say it's extremely common in the UK. Like any idiom, there are a proportion of malaprops who use it inappropriately.

Comment: This is a good description of Catch-22, but not, I think, a good description of [Hobson's choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobson%27s_choice). Hobson's choice is not a choice where both alternatives are undesirable, it is a "choice" which only admits one option, because the other is completely useless or unacceptable.  Perhaps you were thinking of [Sophie's choice](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sophie%27s_choice)?  (Though I can't say that is an exact fit either.)

Comment: @NateEldredge - Was my face red!  All my life (not quite, but...) I've thought that Hobson's choice was "[Damned if you do, damned if you don't.](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/e/eleanorroo109473.html)"  You'd think I'd have looked it up by now, in the age of Google and all...

Comment: Side note: the book was originally titled *Catch-18*, but then Leon Uris published *Mila 18*.  Heller was apparently quite depressed about the conflicting names and it took him several months to bump his title up by four.

Answer (score 8):

Google NGrams shows "catch-22" flatlining, but "catch 22" has had some interesting play:

[image]

Nevertheless, a Google search for "catch-22" (which will be case insensitive and treating the hyphen as optional), shows 5,300,000 hits.

In my own experience it's a fairly common usage and well understood.

**EDIT:**

Actually, *with* the hyphen is preferred; Google Ngrams just needs the hyphen to be delimited by spaces:

[image]

Comment: I think you meant ‘shows’!

Comment: @Rafael Beraldo: You're right, I did. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: That's just some quirkiness with NGrams. Any phrase with a hyphen in it flatlines.

Answer (score -2):

I know this term but I have never used it.

I prefer to use the word "deadlock" for most of the so-called "catch-22" situations.

Comment: A true catch-22 is a *paradox*, while the example given might be said to be a deadlock.  The difference is the element of time.

Comment: True. Now I know the reason why someone vote down this answer.